# Container's session object and not GemFire's session object is invoked inside Servlet Filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-session, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

From a custom Servlet Filter when trying to access a GemFire session object, it is taking the Container's session object instead.  The session object is of the type:

`org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@517957e2`

But from the `Controller`, it is working fine. The session object is of the type:
              `org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper$HttpSessionWrapper@5afe18ce`

On to how we configured GemFire:

We have a legacy retail application. On top, we have used the `2.0.5` version of GemFire. On the *webappintializer* startup,

```
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = 
    new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

rootContext.register(GemfireConfig.class,RootConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class);
```

Since the `springSessionRepositoryFilter` bean was **not** added to the filter chain, we had to explicitly register the filter with `DelegatingFilterProxy` using the below:

```
FilterRegistration.Dynamic springSessionRepositoryFilter = 
    container.addFilter("springSessionRepositoryFilter", DelegatingFilterProxy.class);

springSessionRepositoryFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(
    EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), false, "/*");
```

On the data handling side in order to get the session object, we have a getSession method which returns a session object:

```
ServletRequestAttributes attr = 
    (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();

HttpSession session = attr.getRequest().getSession();
```

When we call the `getSession()` method from `Controller` it is working absolutely fine as designed.  But calling the same from a Servlet Filter eventually gets the Container created session object.

Any help is much appreciated.

Reworked as per comment by @John Blum but still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell, in order for [*Spring Session*](https://spring.io/projects/spring-session#overview), and specifically, [*Spring Session for Pivotal GemFire*](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session-data-geode) (SSDG), to do its job, the `SessionRepositoryFilter` ([Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/2.0.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/session/web/http/SessionRepositoryFilter.html), [Source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/2.0.6.RELEASE/spring-session-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/web/http/SessionRepositoryFilter.java)) must be the **first** Servlet Filter in the filter chain when registered with your (Web) Application Container (e.g. Apache Tomcat, Eclipse Jetty, etc).

Otherwise, if *Spring Session's* `SessionRepositoryFilter` is not the first Servlet Filter in the filter chain, then *Spring Session* will not have intercepted the HTTP request (yet) and won't be able to exercise its opportunity to replace the Container session (by wrapping the `HttpServletRequest` with `SessionRepositoryFilter.SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper`, see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/2.0.6.RELEASE/spring-session-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/web/http/SessionRepositoryFilter.java#L139-L151)) with a `Session` provided by *Spring Session* using the appropriate provider (e.g. like GemFire with SSDG), as determined by the `SessionRepository` implementation, which is set on the `SessionRepositoryFilter` ([here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/2.0.6.RELEASE/spring-session-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/web/http/SessionRepositoryFilter.java#L114-L119)).

The reason why your Spring Web MVC application `Controller` works is, the Java EE Servlet Spec/Container guarantees that all Servlet Filters are invoked before any Servlets are called with the HTTP request (i.e. `HttpServletRequest`).  And, since the Spring Web MVC `DispatcherServlet` is a proper `HttpServlet` and is responsible for invoking your application-defined Spring Web MVC `Controllers`, then the application `Controllers` are guaranteed to see the "replaced" HTTP request (and by extension, HTTP session object).

So, a few housekeeping items... I am not (exactly) certain what you mean by:

1. `2.0.5` version of GemFire.  `2.0.5` refers to the latest/current version of ***Spring Session for Pivotal GemFire***.
2. And `webappinitializer`?

For #2, did you mean that you specifically created a Spring [`WebApplicationInitializer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) to explicitly register the `SessionRepositoryFilter`, manually (as shown above in your code snippet)?

Did you know that *Spring Session* already provides such a class... [`o.s.session.web.context.AbstractHttpServletApplicationInitializer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/2.0.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/session/web/context/AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer.html).

This class is responsible for registering the `SessionRepositoryFilter` using Spring's `DelegatingFilterProxy` class ([here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/2.0.6.RELEASE/spring-session-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/web/context/AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer.java#L118), then [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/2.0.6.RELEASE/spring-session-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/web/context/AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer.java#L134), and [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/2.0.6.RELEASE/spring-session-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/web/context/AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer.java#L182) (notice the `insertBeforeOtherFilters` instance variable, which defaults to `true`), and in the right order, [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/2.0.6.RELEASE/spring-session-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/web/context/AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer.java#L198-L207), well, specifically, [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/2.0.6.RELEASE/spring-session-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/web/context/AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer.java#L206)).

Interestingly enough, it seems like you are doing the same, or similar, thing in your snippet of Filter registration code above.

NOTE: this (programmatical configuration of the Servlet container) only works in Servlet 3.0 containers and later.

You can see how *Spring Session's* `AbstractHttpServletApplicationInitializer` gets used in the [samples](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-session-data-geode-build/2.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html5/#samples), for instance, [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session-data-geode/blob/master/samples/javaconfig/gemfire-clientserver/src/main/java/sample/client/Initializer.java).  More details on the `Initializer` are in the corresponding [guide docs](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-session-data-geode-build/2.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html5/guides/java-gemfire-clientserver.html#java-servlet-container-initialization) for the sample.

One thing different about your Spring `DelegatingFilterProxy` class registration (named after the `SessionRepositoryFilter` bean, named "springSessionRepositoryFilter") that I noticed was, you are passing in the `DelegatingFilterProxy.class` as the second argument to `servletContext.addFilter("filterName", <FilterType>);`, as shown here...

```
FilterRegistration.Dynamic springSessionRepositoryFilter = 
    container.addFilter("springSessionRepositoryFilter", DelegatingFilterProxy.class);
```

However, *Spring Session* (core) itself actually [constructs and initializes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/2.0.6.RELEASE/spring-session-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/web/context/AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer.java#L128-L129) (with the "springSessionRepositoryFilter" bean name) an instance of the Spring `DelegatingFilterProxy` class and [passes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/2.0.6.RELEASE/spring-session-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/web/context/AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer.java#L198) that "instance" to the `ServletContext.addFilter(..)` method (2nd argument) on registration.

I suspect the `ServletContext.addFilter(..)` API itself just uses the default constructor of the Spring `DelegatingProxyFilter` class when constructing/initializing an instance, which is probably the root of your problem, especially when registering the Servlet Filter programmatically.

Food for thought.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

The issue still persists after trying out the suggestions.  Now, we no longer use a separate registration for the `SessionRepositoryFilter`.  We now use:

```
class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer {

 public WebAppInitializer() {
        super(GemfireConfig.class,X.class, Y.class); //X&Y are preexisting config classes in the application context

    }

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

    super.onStartup(container); // newly added inorder to call AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer.startup()
    ...//existing code
    ...//

}
```

Removed the explicit registration of springSessionRepositoryFilter.

We could see this filter being invoked first when we look at the Stack Trace. So, the order of filter chain appears to be intact.

The filter, in which we are facing issue, is being invoked afterwards.  This was the same behavior even without the mentioned changes.

Still, the session object in the filter is from the container.

Comment: You don't need to override the `onStartup(:ServletContext)` method (minor detail, :-)  Not that it should matter, but are you registering your custom, application-specific Servlet Filter using `web.xml`?  So, if you see that the `SessionRepositoryFilter` is the first in the chain of Servlet Filters from your Stack Trace, then upon reviewing your code from the original post, I am sort of wondering what this `RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();` is doing followed by this... `HttpSession session = attr.getRequest().getSession();`?

Comment: It appears you are using the `RequestContextHolder` and `ServletRequestAttributes` classes from the core Spring Framework to obtain the `HttpServletRequest` followed by the `HttpSession`.  I suspect that Spring Session core may not be properly updating Spring's `RequestContextHolder` after the `springSessionRepositoryFilter` has had an opportunity to "replace" the HTTP request/session objects.  Going to do some more digging...

Comment: So, after further digging... 1) It is not the responsibility of Spring Session (and in particular, the `SessionRepositoryFilter`) to update the `RequestContextHolder` state.  2) It is questionable why you are using the `RequestContextHolder` class inside your custom, application-specific Servlet Filter (which as we discussed before, needs to run after the `SessionRepositoryFilter` in the filter chain) to access the `HttpServletRequest` and subsequently access/start an `HttpSession` since `Filter` interface, `doFilter(..)` method accepts the `ServletRequest` and `ServletResponse` instances.

Comment: See here (https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/Filter.html#doFilter-javax.servlet.ServletRequest-javax.servlet.ServletResponse-javax.servlet.FilterChain-).  You could simply cast the `ServletRequest` to an `HttpServletRequest` and call `((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest).getSession()` inside your custom, application-specific Servlet Filter's `doFilter(:ServletRequest, :ServletResponse)` method.

Comment: However, if you must access the HTTP request and session using Spring's `RequestContextHolder` class, for whatever reason (which is not apparent to me, why) inside your custom, application-specific Servlet `Filter`, then you can also employ core Spring's `RequestContextFilter` (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/RequestContextFilter.html) as described in the Javadoc for `RequestContextHolder` (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html).

Comment: Then you must ensure that the Filters are registered in this order: { `SessionRepositoryFilter`, `RequestContextFilter`, "Your Custom, Application-Specific Servlet Filter", all other Servlet `Filters`.

Comment: DISCLAIMER: I have not tried and tested this combination.  Personally, I recommend you to use the `ServletRequest`/`ServletResponse` parameters from your custom, application-specific Servlet `Filter's`, `doFilter(..)` method, to access the HTTP request/session.  Technically, Spring's `RequestContextHolder` is not initialized until the `DispatcherServlet` is invoked.  If you are still experiencing issues after this, I suggest you to write a small test example and publish to GitHub for us to take a look at.  Cheers!

Comment: @John Blum ..It is working now as we changed the usage of RequestContextHolder with ServletRequest/ServletResponse.

Comment: Excellent; glad you figured it out.

Comment: @JohnBlum Amazing support from your end.